# What is the right way to "pause" a route using camel with activemq?

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

My basic problem is that I can only process 7000 messages from one of my queues (across all machines) in any 1 hour time period. I don't see a way to do this with camel or activemq, so I resorted to implementing my own route stopping/starting logic. I see a number of ways to do this, and I've tried a few of them (only to run into problems).

1. `camelContext.stopRoute(route)`: This works in that messages stop being processed, but when I call `camelContext.startRoute(route)`, it leaks a tcp connection which eventually causes the activemq server to hit its limit and die.
2. `camelContext.suspendRoute(route)`: This also stops messages from being processed and does not leak connections, but it appears to kill active consumers (visible in the admin panel) that don't reactivate when I call `camelContext.resumeRoute(route)`. I think that could eventually lead to no messages being processed off that queue at all, even if I resume.
3. implementing a custom `RoutePolicy`. To be fair, I haven't tried this yet, but it seems that it would fall prey to the same problems I had according to the pause method I chose above.

Is there a method for solving this problem that I haven't encountered yet?

Comment: A customer route policy would be the way I'd do it. When you say "according to the pause method I chose above" I thought for a route policy you just called stopConsumer() and startConsumer(), like ThrottlingInflightRoutePolicy does.

Comment: Would a "throller" help? http://camel.apache.org/throttler.html

Comment: @vikingsteve I need to throttle at the queue level across all machines that're processing off that queue. The throttling you mentioned only operates to limit the processing of a single machine.

Comment: @matthelliwell I have tried startConsumer() and stopConsumer() outside of a RoutePolicy which caused a connection leak similar to (1). I suppose I should try the RoutePolicy just for the sake of completeness though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of stopping the route, I would recommend to use the [Throttler EIP](http://camel.apache.org/throttler.html).

```
from("jms:queue:inbox")
    .throttle(7000)
    .timePeriodMillis(1000*60*60)
    .to("log:result", "mock:result");
```

The above example will throttle messages received on `jms:queue:inbox` before being sent to `mock:result` ensuring that a maximum of 7000 messages are sent in any 1 hour window.

Alternatively, for more fine grained control you may define a throttling route policy as shown in Camel's [throttling example](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/examples/camel-example-route-throttling):

```
<route routePolicyRef="myPolicy">
    <from uri="jms:queue:inbox"/>
    <transacted/>
    <to uri="log:+++JMS +++?groupSize=100"/>
    <to ref="foo"/>
</route>
```

The throttling police is defined as follows:

```
<bean id="myPolicy" class="org.apache.camel.impl.ThrottlingInflightRoutePolicy">
    <property name="scope" value="Context"/>
    <!-- when we hit > 20 inflight exchanges then kick in and suspend the routes -->
    <property name="maxInflightExchanges" value="20"/>
    <!-- when we hit lower than 10% of the max = 2 then kick in and resume the routes the default percentage is 70% but in this demo we want a low value -->
    <property name="resumePercentOfMax" value="10"/>
    <!-- output throttling activity at WARN level -->
    <property name="loggingLevel" value="WARN"/>
</bean>
```

**EDIT 1:**

If you need a global throttling, then you may first let **one** consumer read the messages, throttling all messages as described above, then re-send them to another queue and let re-reading and processing them by **>= 1** distributed consumers.

**EDIT 2:**

Alternatively, you may implement your own `ThrottlingInflightRoutePolicy` accessing a central database holding processing information. That way, you don't need a "single node master throttler". However, also the DB may be a single point of failure.

Comment: Can the throttling policy be applied across contexts / machines? Otherwise there is potentially a single point of failure.

Comment: @vikingsteve Thanks for the question. See my *EDIT 2* how that could be handled.

Comment: @Peter Interesting. I hadn't considered having one of the consumers do the throttling, but it would introduce a lot of overhead to manage the consumers being asymmetrical.

I'm not sure how the ThrottlingInflightRoutePolicy implements stopping/starting routes that's different from camelContext.startRoute() or camelContext.resumeRoute() that I mentioned in my question, but since everyone has come out so strongly in favor of it, I'll give it a shot!

Answer (score 1):

Peter's got the best answer(s), but I ended up extending `ThrottlingInflightRoutePolicy`, and there's no great explanation of how that works, so I thought I'd annotate this question a bit and show how I actually solved the problem.

```
public class MyRoutePolicy extends RoutePolicySupport implements CamelContextAware {

    private CamelContext camelContext;
    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private ContextScopedEventNotifier eventNotifier;

    @Override
    public final void setCamelContext(final CamelContext camelContext) {
        this.camelContext = camelContext;
    }

    @Override
    public final CamelContext getCamelContext() {
        return this.camelContext;
    }

    @Override
    public final void onExchangeDone(final Route route, final Exchange exchange) {
        throttle(route);
    }

    private void throttle(final Route route) {
        // this works the best when this logic is executed when the exchange is done
        Consumer consumer = route.getConsumer();

        boolean stop = isRouteMarkedForSuspension(route.getId()) && ((JmsConsumer) route.getConsumer()).isStarted();
        if (stop) {
            try {
                lock.lock();
                stopConsumer(consumer);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                handleException(e);
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }

        // reload size in case a race condition with too many at once being invoked
        // so we need to ensure that we read the most current size and start the consumer if we are already to low
        boolean start = !isRouteMarkedForSuspension(route.getId()) && ((JmsConsumer) route.getConsumer()).isSuspended();
        if (start) {
            try {
                lock.lock();
                startConsumer(consumer);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                handleException(e);
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected final void doStart() throws Exception {
        ObjectHelper.notNull(camelContext, "CamelContext", this);
        eventNotifier = new ContextScopedEventNotifier();
        // must start the notifier before it can be used
        ServiceHelper.startService(eventNotifier);
        // we are in context scope, so we need to use an event notifier to keep track
        // when any exchanges is done on the camel context.
        // This ensures we can trigger accordingly to context scope
        camelContext.getManagementStrategy().addEventNotifier(eventNotifier);
    }

    @Override
    protected final void doStop() throws Exception {
        ObjectHelper.notNull(camelContext, "CamelContext", this);
        camelContext.getManagementStrategy().removeEventNotifier(eventNotifier);
    }

    private class ContextScopedEventNotifier extends EventNotifierSupport {

        @Override
        public void notify(final EventObject event) throws Exception {
            for (Route route : camelContext.getRoutes()) {
                throttle(route);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled(final EventObject event) {
            return event instanceof ExchangeCompletedEvent;
        }

        @Override
        protected void doStart() throws Exception {
            // noop
        }

        @Override
        protected void doStop() throws Exception {
            // noop
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ContextScopedEventNotifier";
        }
    }
}
```

So I added the RoutePolicy above to all of my routes, like this:

```
from(uri).routePolicy(routePolicy).process(runner);
```

`MyRoutePolicy` is a inner class and `isRouteMarkedForSuspension` is defined in the main class.

`throttle` is hit at two points:

- after an exchange (message) is processed. This is useful for figuring out if the consumer should be paused.
- on a notify event through the `ContextScopedEventNotifier`. This is useful for figuring out if the consumer should be resumed.